# Uploading large files to S3 and Server Sessions

Tags: javascript, session, amazon-s3, plupload

I am stuck at a problem I can't seem to figure out a "right" way.
I am uploading files directly to S3 from client side (using Plupload and sprightlysoft class). The server sets the policy document and all; however when uploading large files the session seems to expire and access to bucket would be denied (or at least that's what I think the problem is); the weird thing is that the uploader shows successful upload whilst javascript debugging shows 403 access denied. Any thought or idea on what could be done here? Is there a way to expand the session lifetime while the uploader is still uploading? or maybe another suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case of use Ruby on Rails and carrierwave_direct, a mistake in this lines cause my problem:

```
  def move_to_cache
    true
  end
  def move_to_store
    true
  end
```

I returned false in move_to_cache, and didn't have move_to_store
This lines are usefull when uploading large files